# Add Google Play Services to Android Studio using Gradle

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, android-studio

Im working on simple map app, I added google-play-services.jar and its reference to gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar', 'libs/google-play-services.jar')
}
```

The main activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapui);

GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

layout file

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

But the app crashes on the device

> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown
>   Source) at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown
>   Source)

I tried several ways, same issue, I just want to add google services to Android Studio 0.3 with Gradle 0.6+

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As @Matt said, it is correct, I am here covered also which I did not find in the answer.

To add the Google Play Service library in your application project, follow below steps :-

1) Open the `build.gradle` file of your application module directory. See screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

2) Add new in your dependecies, here you to update the version number whenever you update the Google Play Service.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile files('src/main/libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')

}
```

3) Now Lastly important save your file and click on Sync with `Gradle` Files [image: Icon]in the toolbar.

Comment: how do I know the latest version of the dependency it probably changed already or is it still 4.2.42?

Comment: @Leo
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-location

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 34):

Add this line in the `dependencies` section of your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
```

You don't need to add a `.jar` to your `libs` folder.

**Edit**

As Varun pointed out, you also need to update the SDK to contain the most recent version of the play services.

You can do this by opening up the Android SDK Manager (under the `Window` tab) from Eclipse+ADT, checking the box next to `Google Play services` in the `Extras` folder, and clicking install.

Comment: To add. Also update the SDK to contain the needed version of the play-services, and have the support/google repository installed from the extras section of the SDK manager.

Comment: If you don't need 2.2(1.7% user base?) support and are fine with 2.3 you should use a newer version `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'`

Comment: My gradle says `Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated` because of this rule. I haven't find any not-deprecated method yet.

Comment: I think the latest play services right now is 4.1.  So you should add 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+'

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+' will give you 4.whatever.

Comment: I'm not going to update this answer every time a new version of google play services is released. The specific version number is mostly irrelevant to the intent of the answer.

Answer (score 27):

[image]

[image]

**Hit check on all tools, to be safe**

[image]

**Hit check on API you are working with**

[image]

**Hit check on all extras to be safe**

[image]

**Go to file -> project structure**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Finally go to `build` at the top of the screen and hit `rebuild project`**

Comment: I can't find "com.google.android.gms:play-services" in library dependency.

Comment: did you download the Google Support Library from the SDK Manager?

Comment: that was a ton of a help mate!! Two things helped me
1. Checking all boxes in SDK manager - Extras
2. Adding the location service dependency into app module gradle build through the GUI.
Cheers mate..

Comment: Would be nice if you could past some of the code down.

Answer (score 14):

This didn't work for me, I had to download the Goople Repository in the Android SDK Manager - Extras, to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid including entire google play services, when you use more library then you get **Multidex** exception:

> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64k

So best way to use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```

if you wish to include other services, please refer here:

> https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup (scroll down)

Comment: Imran i'm using compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0' but getting error Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services. plz help

Answer (score 1):

Go to Android SDK Manager, go to Extras, select Google Play Services and Google Repository and then click on 'Install Packages...' button.

Click on 'build.gradle' file, in the code window in editor, then click on 'try again' link button...

Wait until gradle build finish.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the setting -> apps in your android testing phone and search for google play services and click on it, there you will find the version number installed on your device.

```
For me it was 9.6.83
```

then just add your version number to this command below :-

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.83'

- Add this to you build.gradle(app)
- Gradle sync

Later you may get a gradle error saying that the particular repository needs to be installed, Go ahead and download it ! Voila your next gradle sync is successfull.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your app gradle
in dependency block

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'

Comment: Adding detail about where to add this in what file would be helpful. Please edit

Answer (score 0):

Add Google Play Service ads and their feature in your android Project

- Open your Android Studio build.gradle file
- In Dependency add Google Play Service
- implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
- sync your build.gradle file